# wrap not sending widgets to next line

Tags: flutter, user-interface, spacing

In flutter, I have this Widget :

```
 Wrap(
                    runSpacing: 5.0,
                    spacing: 5.0,
                    children: GenerateSimilarInterests.generate(
                        compareTo: user!,
                        localUser: (BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>
                          (context).state
                        as ProfileLoaded)
                            .user),
                  ),
```

And it's looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, a person icon is going off of the widget. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include what is it parent widget?